# Identical query & instance but other execution plans & performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan

I have 2 identical queries . One is executed with parameters, the other is executed with hardcoded values. Somehow sql server is creating 2 different execution plans for the 2 queries. The first one is almost instantaniously completed. The other one takes +- 2 seconds to complete. The application is creating the second query(which takes the longest) .

How do i make the parameterized query take the same execution plan as the other one? I already tried rebuilding the statistics & indexes but with no success.

The execution plans in the screenshot are scrolled to the right top position, showing a clear difference in approach.

[image: sql execution plan]

Comment: Is there any way you can post the XML of these post-execution plans?

Comment: (Essentially the choices are to rewrite to use a parameterised inline table valued function instead of a view or use the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint more details in this [blog post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views))

Comment: @MartinSmith Is a possible solution not to just use OPTIMIZE FOR and set the parameter values there to the whatever the OP had for the first query?  That way it'll inject a compiled parameter value?  Curious, haven't tested it out yet.

Comment: @ThomasStringer - No. It has to treat the predicate values as constants. Which is only achieved by actual literal values or `RECOMPILE`. (From Paul White's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15304023/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, cool.  Thanks for the info, great stuff.

Comment: @Martin, option(recompile) does the trick. If you post it as an answer I will mark it so

Comment: Glad it worked. I'd just be rehashing the same links from my answer in the possible duplicate though so won't answer here as well (this will likely be closed as duplicate at some point)

Comment: @MartinSmith how did you know this was about a windowed function in the view? I see the segment operator in the first query plan. Was that the only clue?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - And that the filter operator on the left of the bad plan has loads of predicates that get pushed down into seeks in the good plan.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson (The OP had uploaded the XML version of the plans but that comment with the link has gone now)

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks, that explains a lot. It is really hard to tell from the picture alone.